# Is there something wrong with using this pattern in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

Everywhere where I saw React code written by other people and also me for most of my time since I started working in React a year ago I saw this kind of pattern for passing props.

```
    <Player 
     currentSong={currentSong}
     isPlaying={isPlaying}
     setIsPlaying={setIsPlaying}
     setCurrentSong={setCurrentSong}
    />
```

I've just realised recently that you can write the same thing like this:

```
<Player {...{ currentSong, isPlaying, setIsPlaying, setCurrentSong }} />
```

Is there something wrong with this or why is nobody using this implementation?

Comment: I personally think it's more difficult to read. Option A is verbose but clear.

Comment: I often use the spread syntax for passing props down,  but remember the spread syntax is not free,.  So you might get some slight performance issue if used everywhere.

Comment: Are you always guaranteed, that all props have a local variable with the exact same name, that it's supposed to take?

Comment: @Keith true...I was thinking that maybe be one thing

Comment: @ASDFGerte no but a lot of time it happens and for the ones that don't you can just pass them as usual

Comment: Well, nothing is stopping you, just don't accidentally rename your local variables either, cause that would break everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second form you're using is the object [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Basically, an elegant way would be:

```
   const setIsPlaying = true;
   const currentSong = 'my girl';

   const props = {
     currentSong,
     isPlaying: true,
     setIsPlaying,
   };

   return (<Player {...props} />);
```

Note I'm using the [shorthand form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) to pass object properties **setIsPlaying** and **currentSong** (when the property has the same name of the variable in the same scope, don't need to repeat).

Comment: that wouldn't work when I am passing props to more components in the same component...I wouldn't really want to create a lot of objects just to pass them down later. However I won't say that I'll keep this pattern for now...I am just experiemnting...as one answer above says it might have an impact on performance due to the destructuring, but I doubt it would be that much.